# Layout bootstrap mobile navbar issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with **navbar** in **mobile version** of site. I'm using **bootstrap**.
In mobile version, I'm using a collapsed navbar, not in the foreground but in the background (on the screen). When I have slider before, the collapsed menu was behind this slider.

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- facebook & phone number -->
      <div class="row face-phone">

          <div class="pull-left">
              <a  href="index.html">
                  <img src="images/logo_new.png" alt="logotype" class="logotype" />
              </a>
          </div>

          <div class="pull-right face-text">
              <span class="small">
                  TEL: +48 605 26 33 99 <span class="mar-left-20"></span>ul. Podgórna 43a / 2 Zielona Góra
              </span>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Newbello-Salon-Depilacji-i-Kosmetologii-Laserowej-288363824707329/" target="_blank">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up mar-left-20" area-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ./row logotype, facebook, phone number -->

      <!-- navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="newbello">
            <p class="pull-left">
              Witamy na stronie naszego salonu kosmetycznego
            </p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- ./row hello-text -->

        <hr>

        <div class="row mar-top-20">

          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <p>
              <strong>
                Naszym priorytetem jest profesjonalna obsługa i najwyższej jakości zabiegi
              </strong>
              Wszystkie kosmetyki i urządzenia, które wprowadzamy do naszej
              oferty przechodzą liczne testy i są poddawane gruntownej analizie
              efektywności i bezpieczeństwa stosowania.
              <strong>
                Stawiamy przede wszystkim na skuteczność!
              </strong>.
              Do każdego klienta podchodzimy indywidualnie, służymy radą i
              pomocą w dobraniu odpowiednich zabiegów gabinetowych oraz
              profesjonalnej i kompleksowej pielęgnacji domowej.
            </p>

            <h3 class="mar-top-40">
              W czym jesteśmy najlepsi?
            </h3>

            <h4 class="mar-top-40">
              Deppilacja laserowa, depilacja SHR i nie tylko
            </h4>

            <p class="mar-top-40">
              Depilacją zajmujemy się nieprzerwanie od ponad 5 lat.
              Dzięki setkom osób, którym w tym czasie mieliśmy przyjemność
              pomóc, zgromadziliśmy szeroką wiedzę dotyczącą diagnostyki
              skóry i wyboru odpowiedniej metody depilacji. Nasze ogromne
              doświadczenie pozwala nam znacznie zredukować ryzyko
              podrażnień, bólu i innych nieprzyjemnych odczuć związanych z
              usuwaniem zbędnego owłosienia.
            </p>

            <h4 class="mar-top-40">
              Odmładzanie i zabiegi pielęgnacyjne
            </h4>

            <p class="mar-top-40">
              Dzisiejszy trend piękna to dbałość o wygląd zewnętrzny.
              Dlatego skutecznie odmładzany koszystając z najnowszych odkryć
              medycyny, kosmetologii, chemii i techniki oraz wykorzystując
              zabiegi oparte na najlepszej jakości kosmetykach. Takie
              działanie gwarantuje zarówno wysoką skuteczność zabiegu, ale
              także komfort i co najważniejsze bezpieczeństwo naszych klientów.
            </p>
          </div><!-- ./col -->

        </div>
        <!-- ./row mar-top-20 -->




    <!-- Core Javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is screenshot what is it look like: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmGeV.png)

Comment: maybe add a bootply/fiddle so we can see the problem in live-demo. and add css (sounds like a z-index problem)

Answer (score 2):

Now fix it, please update following **External** Resources / **Bootstrap CDN**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/cdbyo06x/1/)

```
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- facebook & phone number -->
      <div class="row face-phone">

          <div class="pull-left">
              <a  href="index.html">
                  <img src="images/logo_new.png" alt="logotype" class="logotype" />
              </a>
          </div>

          <div class="pull-right face-text">
              <span class="small">
                  TEL: +48 605 26 33 99 <span class="mar-left-20"></span>ul. Podgórna 43a / 2 Zielona Góra
              </span>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Newbello-Salon-Depilacji-i-Kosmetologii-Laserowej-288363824707329/" target="_blank">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up mar-left-20" area-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ./row logotype, facebook, phone number -->

      <!-- navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="newbello">
            <p class="pull-left">
              Witamy na stronie naszego salonu kosmetycznego
            </p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- ./row hello-text -->

        <hr>

        <div class="row mar-top-20">

          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <p>
              <strong>
                Naszym priorytetem jest profesjonalna obsługa i najwyższej jakości zabiegi
              </strong>
              Wszystkie kosmetyki i urządzenia, które wprowadzamy do naszej
              oferty przechodzą liczne testy i są poddawane gruntownej analizie
              efektywności i bezpieczeństwa stosowania.
              <strong>
                Stawiamy przede wszystkim na skuteczność!
              </strong>.
              Do każdego klienta podchodzimy indywidualnie, służymy radą i
              pomocą w dobraniu odpowiednich zabiegów gabinetowych oraz
              profesjonalnej i kompleksowej pielęgnacji domowej.
            </p>

            <h3 class="mar-top-40">
              W czym jesteśmy najlepsi?
            </h3>

            <h4 class="mar-top-40">
              Deppilacja laserowa, depilacja SHR i nie tylko
            </h4>

            <p class="mar-top-40">
              Depilacją zajmujemy się nieprzerwanie od ponad 5 lat.
              Dzięki setkom osób, którym w tym czasie mieliśmy przyjemność
              pomóc, zgromadziliśmy szeroką wiedzę dotyczącą diagnostyki
              skóry i wyboru odpowiedniej metody depilacji. Nasze ogromne
              doświadczenie pozwala nam znacznie zredukować ryzyko
              podrażnień, bólu i innych nieprzyjemnych odczuć związanych z
              usuwaniem zbędnego owłosienia.
            </p>

            <h4 class="mar-top-40">
              Odmładzanie i zabiegi pielęgnacyjne
            </h4>

            <p class="mar-top-40">
              Dzisiejszy trend piękna to dbałość o wygląd zewnętrzny.
              Dlatego skutecznie odmładzany koszystając z najnowszych odkryć
              medycyny, kosmetologii, chemii i techniki oraz wykorzystując
              zabiegi oparte na najlepszej jakości kosmetykach. Takie
              działanie gwarantuje zarówno wysoką skuteczność zabiegu, ale
              także komfort i co najważniejsze bezpieczeństwo naszych klientów.
            </p>
          </div><!-- ./col -->

        </div>
        <!-- ./row mar-top-20 -->




    <!-- Core Javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```